# convert Table data as a JSON Object

Tags: angularjs

Hi I have created a table in which we can add and remove the table row on button click.

Now I want to send the table data as a Json object to the server. could anyone help me by suggesting the way how to convert the table data as a JSON object.
I tried doing in the following way but it's not affecting.

```
<title>Test</title>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module("createDelivery", []);
app.controller("MyController", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.deliveryDetails = [
        {
            'fname1':'Muhammed',
            'fname2':'Muhammed',
            'fname3':'Muhammed',
            'fname4':'Muhammed',
            'fname5':'Muhammed',
            'fname6':'Muhammed',
            'fname7':'Muhammed',
            'fname8':'Muhammed'
        },

        {
            'fname1':'Muhammed',
            'fname2':'Muhammed',
            'fname3':'Muhammed',
            'fname4':'Muhammed',
            'fname5':'Muhammed',
            'fname6':'Muhammed',
            'fname7':'Muhammed',
            'fname8':'Muhammed'
        }];

        $scope.addNew = function(cdDetails){
            $scope.deliveryDetails.push({ 
                'fname1': "", 
                'fname2': "", 
                'fname3': "", 
                'fname4': "", 
                'fname5': "", 
                'fname6': "", 
                'fname7': "", 
                'fname8': ""
            });
        };

        $scope.remove = function(){
            var newDataList=[];
            $scope.selectedAll = false;
            angular.forEach($scope.deliveryDetails, function(selected){
                if(!selected.selected){
                    newDataList.push(selected);
                }
            }); 
            $scope.deliveryDetails = newDataList;
        };

    $scope.checkAll = function () {
        if (!$scope.selectedAll) {
            $scope.selectedAll = true;
        } else {
            $scope.selectedAll = false;
        }
        angular.forEach($scope.deliveryDetails, function(cdDetails) {
            cdDetails.selected = $scope.selectedAll;
        });
    };    
    $scope.getData = function(cdDetails) 
    {
            alert("Check");
            var jsonString;
            jsonString = angular.toJson(cdDetails);
            //JSON.stringify(jsonString);                               
            $http
                ({
                    url: "/scheduler/createDelivery",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: jsonString

                }).success(function(response) {
                    alert("success : : "+jsonString);
                    $scope.value = response;
                }).error(function(error) {
                    alert("error::"+error);
                });

            //window.location.reload();  
            //document.write("\nString value "+jsonString);                 
    };  

}]);
</script>
```

```
                    <form ng-submit="addNew()">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">

                                <tr>
                                    <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()" /></th>
                                    <th style="background-color: #337ab7;color: white;border-right: 1px solid white;padding-bottom:4px;border-top-left-radius:15px"><label class="col-md-1 control-label" style="width:100%;text-align: center;">PO#</label></th>
                                    <th style="background-color: #337ab7;color: white;border-right: 1px solid white;padding-bottom:4px;"><label class="col-md-1 control-label" style="width:100%;text-align: center;">BOL#</label></th>
                                    <th style="background-color: #337ab7;color: white;border-right: 1px solid white;padding-bottom:4px;"><label class="col-md-1 control-label" style="width:100%;text-align: center;">Pick Up Date</label></th>
                                    <th style="background-color: #337ab7;color: white;border-right: 1px solid white;padding-bottom:4px;"><label class="col-md-1 control-label" style="width:100%;text-align: center;">Units</label></th>
                                    <th style="background-color: #337ab7;color: white;border-right: 1px solid white;padding-bottom:4px;"><label class="col-md-1 control-label" style="width:100%;text-align: center;">Quantity</label></th>
                                    <th style="background-color: #337ab7;color: white;border-right: 1px solid white;padding-bottom:4px;"><label class="col-md-1 control-label" style="width:100%;text-align: center;">Weight</label></th>
                                    <th style="background-color: #337ab7;color: white;border-right: 1px solid white;padding-bottom:4px;"><label class="col-md-1 control-label" style="width:100%;text-align: center;">Load Type</label></th>
                                    <th style="background-color: #337ab7;color: white;border-right: 1px solid white;padding-bottom:4px;"><label class="col-md-1 control-label" style="width:100%;text-align: center;">Commodity Type</label></th>
                                    <th style="background-color: #337ab7;color: white;padding-bottom:4px;border-top-right-radius:15px"><label class="col-md-1 control-label" style="width:100%;">+/-</label></th>
                                </tr>


                                <tr style="background-color: rgba(248, 248, 255, 0.81);" ng-repeat="cdDetails in deliveryDetails">
                                   <td style="border-right: 1px solid white;">
                                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="cdDetails.selected"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid white;">
                                        <input type="text"  ng-model="cdDetails.fname1" required/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid white;">
                                        <input type="text"  ng-model="cdDetails.fname2" required/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid white;">
                                        <input type="text"  ng-model="cdDetails.fname3" required/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid white;">
                                        <input type="text"  ng-model="cdDetails.fname4" required/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid white;">
                                        <input type="text"  ng-model="cdDetails.fname5" required/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid white;">
                                        <input type="text"  ng-model="cdDetails.fname6" required/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid white;">
                                        <input type="text"  ng-model="cdDetails.fname7" required/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="border-right: 1px solid white;">
                                        <input type="text"  ng-model="cdDetails.fname8" required/>
                                    </td>


                                </tr>

                        </table>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input ng-hide="!deliveryDetails.length" type="button"  ng-click="remove()" value="Remove">
                            <input type="submit"  value="Add New">
                             <button type="button" name = "createDelivery"class="col-sm-2 btn btn-primary" style="width:25%" ng-click="getData(cdDetails);">Create Delivery</button>

                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: please don't use inline styles makes it hard to read your markup.

Comment: really not clear what your specific problem is

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correclty, `$scope.deliveryDetails` is the JavaScript Objecct representing your table.

You can simply do:

```js
$http({
  url: "/scheduler/createDelivery",
  dataType: 'json',
  method: 'POST',
  data: $scope.deliveryDetails
}).success(function(response) {
  alert("success : : " + response);
  $scope.value = response;
}).error(function(error) {
  alert("error::" + error);
});
```

Angular will internally invoke `angular.toJson` and convert it into JSON string.

Comment: If I do so, it's not adding the row itself. And the default rows are not being populated with default value son executing the code.

Comment: note that `success()` and `error()` are deprecated per `$http` docs. Should use promise `then()` instead. Also simpler to use `$http.post()`

Comment: @AnjaliSrivastava Why do you want to send the entire table data to server for adding a row?

Comment: I want the user to add as many rows as he want...n each cell value needs to be entered by the user. n once it's done and user click on create delivery i wannt the complete data tto be send to the server.  I have done till the part of add and removing rows... but i have no clue how to send the data to server...please help...its very important as of now

Comment: @AnjaliSrivastava looking at your code, you're binding all the user input to `$scope.deliveryDetails`, so that's what you should be sending to server... You probably copy pasted my code and it might have caused errors since `jsonString` is `undefined` or something. Do you have errors in console...?

Comment: Do you have any refernce for converting table data to JSON object.

Comment: @AnjaliSrivastava I'm looking at it in from the wrong point of view... working with AngularJS is not like working with jQuery where we pluck data from DOM... with angular You manipulate the data, and DOM just represents the current state of data... So in your case you have the whole data in `scope.deliveryDetails` object. That's what your table is representing... You just need to send it to backend. What other *"table data"* are you expecting to retrieve which is not  in `scope.deliveryDetails` ?